# How to set up database properly in django for heroku?

Tags: database, django, heroku

I know this question sounds stupid and I have followed the tutorial heroku provides but everytime I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` it will complain the following:

> ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

I did not change setting.DATABASE, I leaved it as it was created by django-admin.py.

How to set the database properly? I have searched around but cannot find an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here on how to use a postgresql db with django on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#django-settings

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use the dj-database-url package https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url.

and configure your settings like that : [Sample project](https://github.com/belug23/gswd-Lessons-01-02/blob/master/microblog/settings/base.py#L25)

Comment: You need to enable the developer postgresql database addon package before it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the add-on enabled you should simply insert:

```
import dj_database_url
if dj_database_url.config():
    DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

after your initial definition of DATABASES in your settings.py.

Make sure that `dj-database-url==0.2.1` is in the requirements.txt

That should be everything to enable it on heroku.